# There was an unknown error while processing the request. Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

[image: firebase giving error for specific bundle id ios]

I have App on firebase everything was working fine push notification, phone authentication. but yesterday it stopped working. I search for answers on Stack overflow & other blog. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution I tried here, but no luck ...**

- Force refresh browser. try login in incognito mode.
- Login/Logout many times.
- Deleting ios App and Added it again.
- Contact to firebase support team, but its 2 day's still no response.

**Solution worked for me ...**

- I Delete the project from firebase and Create a new Project.

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

Some steps for troubleshooting, that most often help in such situations.

1. Force a refresh of your browser with cmd-shift-R, to make sure you have a completely fresh version of the Firebase console.
2. Check the JavaScript console of your browser for any relevant error messages.
3. If you have any plugins in your browser blocking content (such as ads), please disable those and try again.

If neither of those gives a hint to the cause of the problem, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. Be sure to include information about the OS you run on, the version of your browser, and anything from #1.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I tried the above steps but no luck. I contact firebase support its 2 day's still no response.